# how to set the nib name of a view controller in interfacebuilder

Tags: objective-c, ios6, storyboard, xcode4.5, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using multiple views in my project and I need to navigate from one another and I dont know how to do that when I googled I got some answer based on the nib names now I'm more confused How can I set The nib name of the View controller using interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Click on the Files Owner and Click Identity Inspector and write your class name there.....**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the window in the editor area. Than go the the Inspector [Selection Bar](http://beginning-mac-programming.timisted.net/images/posts/generalOverview/13-Xcode4Inspectors.png) and open the `File Inspector`. There you set the window nib name you can later call in your code.

[image]